# issue no resource indentifier found for attribute Xamarin in visual studio

Tags: xamarin

I have updated xamarin to stable. I have also updated all sdks but still I am getting this error while building xamarin.forms project..

```
Build FAILED.

Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabIndicatorColor' in package 'App1.Droid'
Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabGravity' in package 'App1.Droid'
Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabMode' in package 'App1.Droid'
```

Comment: What is the contents on your `Tabbar.axml` file in the specified folder? It would be way easier to help you if that was supplied

Comment: Actually it is a default tabbar that is loaded when i created xamarin.form new project..I have changed my compile using andriod version to 4.4 kitkat then above error was solved. However i got another new issue....No resource found that matches the given name  attr 'android:datePickerDialogTheme. Previously i was using android 6.0 @Demitrian